# Create Polygon on Google Map By dragging mouse

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am first time using Google Map..

I have to add the Google Map in my web application with following functionality.

1. User can create polygon on the Map by using Mouse.
2. Then the values of polygon's Lat/Lon will be saved in the Database.
3. Like wise he can create multiple polygons but with the restriction that any polygons should not be overlapped.

Please help me on it..
Thaks in advance

Comment: What problem are you having? What have you done so far? Can we see your code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as rendering the polys I would consider using a open source tool kit that already does that .  [Open Layers](http://openlayers.org/) is a nice javascript library that works with Google Maps enables you to draw overlays and collect lat lon information, etc.  As far as the database entries and overlapping issues see the comments on your question.